# How to open a new vscode tab but not a new vscode window when using "code ." in terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, visual-studio-code, iterm2

As the title says, I input "code ." in my iterm2 terminal to open a folder in my vscode, and want it be opened in my current vscode window(in other words, in a new tab), but not create a new window to open it. And I'm using macos, so what should I do?

Comment: Many apps have a pref for 'prefer tabs' or similar wording. idk VSCode, but that's what you need to look for.

Comment: I’m not sure I follow. VS Code cannot open folders in tabs. Only the editor pane is tabbed, showing open files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "add" option add a folder to the last active window instead of opening it in a new window, e.g.

```sh
code ./my-first-folder
code --add ./my-second-folder
```

From the usage documentation:

```sh
➜  ~ code --help | grep add
 -a --add <folder>                          Add folder(s) to the last active
```

Comment: I want to make the folder into a new tab, but this method you said is add the folder to the currrent tab. But still thanks a lot, it also helps.

Answer (score 1):

Type the following command in the VS Code terminal to open your folder in the last active VS Code window (rather than a new window)!

`code --reuse-window .`

or

`code -r .`

VS Code CLI Help Docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In macOS Sonoma:
*System Settings > Desktop & Dock > Windows -> Prefer tabs when opening documents = Always*

This makes sure that when I run `code .` in a folder or `code ./some-folder` it will open as a new tab in vscode.

Answer (score -1):

Open the relevant VS Code project first. The Command Palette will then open when you press Ctrl+Shift+P. Alternately pick the Command Palette under View. Choose Create New File from the list.